# change size of Frame even if there widget python

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

hi is there any way  to change width and height of widget even if there's widget?
i have code like this

```
  form = Tk()
  form.geometry("500x500")

  def click():
      global frame
      frame.config(height = 0 ,width =  0)


  frame = LabelFrame(form , text = "vaaja")
  frame.place(x = 20 , y = 30)
   Label(frame, text ="1").grid(row = 0,column = 0 )
   Label(frame, text =  "2").grid(row = 1 ,column = 0 )

   Button(form , text="Click", command = click).place(x = 200 ,  y = 200)

   form.mainloop()
```

and when I click the button the size of the frame is the same ( I'cant use grid_forget() for labels and then change the size of frame)

Comment: Using place, and setting a widget width and height to zero is highly unusual. Is this really what you need to do, or are you actually trying to solve some other problem and you're guessing that setting the width and height to zero is the proper solution? I can't think of any case where that would be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `place`, you have two solutions: you can use place to set the width and height to zero, or you can turn geometry propagation off.

**Using place to set the width and height**

place allows you to define the width and the height of the placed widget, so in your `click` function you can do this:

```
def click():
    frame.place_configure(width=0, height=0)
```

**Turning geometry propagation off**

A frame is resized to fit its contents by something called "geometry propagation". If you turn this off, you can control the size of the frame with the width and height options of the frame itself. Usually it's better to let Tkinter decide the size for you, but sometimes there's a need to have an explicit size, which is why it's possible to turn geometry propagation off.

Since you are using `grid` to manage the widgets internal to the frame, you need to use `grid_propagate(False)` to turn geometry propagation off for that frame:

```
frame.grid_propagate(False)
```

By doing so, you're responsible for setting the initial width and height of the widget, though you could leave propagation on to get the initial size, then turn it off with the button click in order to work around that issue.

There's an interesting bug (or feature...) in that if you set the width and height to zero, Tkinter won't redraw the window. At least, it doesn't on the Mac. I don't recall the workaround for that because I never, ever need to set a widget to a zero size, but setting it to 1x1 pixel makes it nearly invisible.